# My Dovecot and Postfix server on Ubuntu not working

Tags: email, ubuntu, server, postfix-mta, dovecot

I recently started renting a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS from DigitalOcean. The intent was to run a cheaper email system instead of alternatives like GSuite and Microsoft Business for me and a fellow developer, and split the costs. I've setup very basic email servers before, but in this case, since we both have our own domains and users, using virtual domains/virtual users is a must.

I followed a tutorial [here](https://multiformeingegno.it/riflessioni/setup-postfix-and-dovecot-storing-virtual-users-in-mysql-database/), but my server won't let me connect. When I try viewing logs in any sort of way, everything seems fine. Entering the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep dovecot`, then monitoring the results as I try and log in only produces this:

```
Sep 29 03:11:16 MEMail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<sysadmin@meproduction.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28028, secured, session=<lUrg7Pl2ls9/AAAB>
Sep 29 03:11:16 MEMail dovecot: imap(sysadmin@meproduction.org): Logged out in=44 out=870
```

That's all the logs I was able to find. `/var/logs/mail.log` was empty, and postfix doesn't seem to show anything what-so-ever. When I try and login via SquirrelMail, CloudFlare ( my NameServer ) shows a page saying a 502, but only if I login to a valid account. Entering an invalid user just says that my login is incorrect, as you'd expect.

What logs am I missing, or maybe steps the tutorial messed up that you see? I would like to get the email system running ASAP, because I don't want to setup anything else until it's done, and some things require it ( like adding a spam filter, and S/MIME, and adding all those extra DNS and SSL features for security ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find an answer. Apparently the tutorial I followed must've been formatted incorrectly, or done something wrong. After reverting my VPS, and following a different tutorial, I was able to set it up. If anybody else is trying to setup something like I did, follow this tutorial [from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot). I recommend looking firstly for tutorials from them, as they're usually well made and work well.